# Language switcher removes url store code

Tags: magento-1.7, ce-1.7.0.2, language

When I change language via the language switcher, the url changes for the corresponding url in the other language, but the url store code disappears from the url. Here is an example :

Starting url : example.com/fr/product-fr
Switcher url : example.com/fr/product-fr?___from_store=fr
Final url : example.com/product-en
Expected url : example.com/en/product-en

My settings:
System->Configuration->Web->Add Store Code to URLs = Yes

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Cache refreshed?

Answer (score 2):

code in url comes if we have multiple website not when we have multile store view which is the case of multi language website.
But if we forcefully wants our code in url then we have to write Rewrite Rule in .htaccess .
Follow this link to implement it.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18958585/magento-multi-language-rewrites-seo-fix

Comment: Thanks for your input, but this won't solve my problem, it will only redirect to a specified language. I want to add the language code that the user selected from the language switcher in the url.